# (WPF Datagrid) How do I determine the Column Index of an Item

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid, wpf-controls

How do i return the column index of an item within a WPF Datagrid, when I click on a cell
I'm using Visual Studio 2010/VB.Net

Answer (score 9):

You can use below code directly to get selected cells column index.

```
int index = datagrid.SelectedCells[0].Column.DisplayIndex;
```

Answer (score 9):

You tried use this at the Event Click for Column Index?

```
int columnIndex = dataGrid.CurrentColumn.DisplayIndex;
```

I'm using this code in MouseDoubleClick Event or PreviewKeyUp and works perfectly.

Comment: This might work on the Win Forms datagrid, but not on the WPF datagrid. The latter has no CurrentColumn property.

Comment: This helped me out, works perfectly on WPF DataGrid.

Answer (score 4):

Everybody tells about this solution

```
Int32 columnIndex = dataGridScannedFiles.SelectedCells[0].Column.DisplayIndex;
```

and yes it works but nobody tells that we have to set the Display index first fro every column, maybe it is quite obvious for Experts to get that, but for novices, it's an unfamiliar thing

There are two ways to set it:-

1. You can set it in XAML part.

I don't know how to set it for custom columns like

```
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                   <DataTemplate>                                                            
    <CheckBox x:Name="ChkItem" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Sno}"/>                                
</DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

so I preferred the other Way

2. Created A function

   private void SetDisplayIndexforGridViewColumns()
   {
   Int32 ColumnCount = dt.Columns.Count;

   ```
            for (int i = 0; i < ColumnCount; i++) 
            {
                dataGridScannedFiles.Columns[i].DisplayIndex = i;

            }
        }
   ```

`dt` is my Data Table

and I am assigning Display Indexes to it

Now if you use

```
Int32 columnIndex = dataGridScannedFiles.SelectedCells[0].Column.DisplayIndex;
```

then You will surely Get the Index

Answer (score 3):

`DataGridCells` do not have a Click event, they have a `Selected` event but that is normally fired for each cell in a row when you click on a cell. `GotFocus` might be a better choice.

e.g.

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <EventSetter Event="GotFocus" Handler="CellClick"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```

and:

```
    void CellClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridCell cell = sender as DataGridCell;
        MessageBox.Show(cell.Column.DisplayIndex.ToString());
    }
```

`DataGridCell.Column.DisplayIndex` seems to return an appropriate index, if it somehow is not enough you can use `DataGrid.Columns.IndexOf(DataGridCell.Column)`.

Comment: DataGrid.Columns.IndexOf(DataGridCell.Column) gives the correct index for finding the a cell using the presenter (presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index)) even when the columns have been moved by the user, the columns display index does not

Answer (score 0):

**To Get the Column index of particular column name from DataGrid (in wpf using linq)**

```
  int index = DataGrid.Columns.Single(c => c.Header.ToString() == "Department").DisplayIndex;
```