# get row index of selected item in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to get the row index for the selected item in a data grid bound to a  `DataTable`.

Here is my attempt (based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20170006/10288261)):

```
private void ShowRowIndex_Btn(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int editedRowIndex = myDataGrid.Items.IndexOf(myDataGrid.CurrentItem);
    MessageBox.Show(editedRowIndex.ToString());
}

<DataGrid CellEditEnding="PriceListDG_CellEditEnding"  RowEditEnding="MyDataGrid_RowEditEnding" Name="priceListDataGrid" />
```

Unfortunately I always get -1 as the result.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? There's probably a much easier way than trying to port some Winforms style code directly to WPF.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36529374/8584235

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853202/wpf-datagrid-how-do-i-determine-the-column-index-of-an-item) might also be helpful.

Comment: @ikerbera That's about columns...I need row

Comment: @RameshVerma That's not workung for me since `dg` always `null`

Comment: Wait, your DataGrid is always `null`? How do you expect to find anything then?

Comment: @ikerbera No, my datagrid is not null, I wrote that `var dg = sender as DataGrid` from the link that you gave returns that dg is null, I assume that because the lineked answer of you isn't the same problem as mine

Comment: Can you show your WPF code for the grid? Do you have your grid linked to the `ShowRowIndex_Btn` event?

Comment: @ikerbera No, Ihave button linked to this event, not grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the index of the row currently being edited, you can do it directly inside your `RowEditEnding` event:

```
private void OnRowEditEnding(object sender, .DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    var index = e.Row.GetIndex();
}
```

Comment: You need to add the namespace: using System.Linq;